# Implementing Promise Reject with dialog.showSaveDialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to implement file-saving with `dialog.showSaveDialog` with the following two approaches:

***Approach 1:***

```
const pObj = dialog.showSaveDialog(window, options);
pObj.then(
  onResolved => {
    filename = onResolved.filePath;
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, arg);
  },
  onRejected => {console.log('Promise rejected')}
);
```

***Approach 2:***

```
const pObj = dialog.showSaveDialog(window, options);
pObj.then(
  onResolved => {
    filename = onResolved.filePath;
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, arg);
  }
).catch(err => {
  console.log('No file saved');
});
```

When I click `Cancel` instead of `Save` in the dialog window, Approach 1 throw me an error message, saying that the promise error is uncaught. Approach 2 works fine (i.e., it displays the text `No file saved`.
Why doesn't the `pObj` in Approach 1 execute the `onRejected` handler? Doesn't `then()` method accept two handlers, one for resolved state and one for rejected state? Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method does indeed accept two handlers, one for resolved state and one for rejected state. The `reject` handler is only called when something goes wrong; however, clicking `Cancel` instead of `Save`  doesn't trigger an error, it simply returns a different result through the `resolve` handler.

This is clearly explained in the documentation about [dialog.showSaveDialog()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options):

> Returns `Promise<Object>` - Resolve with an object containing the
> following:
>
> • `canceled` Boolean - whether or not the dialog was canceled.
>
> • `filePath` String (optional) - If the dialog is canceled, this will be `undefined`.

This should work then (untested):

```
const pObj = dialog.showSaveDialog(window, options);
pObj.then(
  onResolved => {
    if (!onResolved.canceled) {
        filename = onResolved.filePath;
        fs.writeFileSync(filename, arg);
    }
  },
  onRejected => {console.log('Promise rejected')}
);
```